# LWC controller accessing SObject Metadata

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, getobjectinfo

I have imported metadata into an LWC controller :

```
import SENIORITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/xx_Seniority__c';
```

...

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: SENIORITY_OBJECT }) objectInfo;
```

If I later do:

```
console.log('scale : '+this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale);
```

then it fails with a very cryptic error.

But if I 'gently' drill down into the objectInfo, checking each step, then it works:

```
    if (this.objectInfo) {
        console.log('objectInfo');
        if (this.objectInfo.data) {
            console.log('objectInfo.data')
            if (this.objectInfo.data.fields) {
                console.log('objectInfo.data.fields');
                if (this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c) {
                    console.log('objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c');
                    if (this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale) {
                        console.log('objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale = '+this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //the line which fails if the above if() blocks aren't there!!
    console.log('scale : '+this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale);
```

With the if() blcoks, I can see that the entire structure `this.objectInfo.data.fields.xx__Rate__c.scale` is present, but the final console.log() can only access it if preceded by the nested if() blocks checking every level.

Why?

Comment: what is this "cryptic" error? can you provide it?

Comment: and how are you trying to get value for `scale`? inside lifecycle event, or by UI user interaction?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?.) which enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

additionally, you can use a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (??) at the end of your chain to assign a default value if the chain evaluates to a nullish value.

so, in the end, your object chain would look something like this:

```
topLevelObject?.nestedObjectProp1?.nestedObjectProp2?.property ?? 'default value'
```